# /bin/sh line 4 : 31482 segment fault, when I run a c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing

When i'm running a c++ program I get the following error

> /bin/sh line 4 : 31482 segment fault.

Does someone knows what it means? If I gdb it, it runs fine. Does my c++ program have bug or /bin/sh?
My c++ program is a unit test case program.

Answer (score 2):

> /bin/sh line 4 : 31482 segment fault.

This message means the process 31482 (which was run at the 4th line of your shell script) received a *SIGSEVG* signal.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls
./bad_program
ls
```

If the program `bad_program` segfaults, the following message appears:

> test.sh: line 3: 2130 Segmentation fault (core dumped) ./bad_program